# How to get the user's canonical ID for adding a S3 permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to add a S3 permission for a specific user. The AWS console is asking me for the Canonical ID for the user.
I used the AWS CLI command `aws iam list-users` to retrieve the list of users, but there was no "Canonical ID" field, and the "User ID" is not recognized, giving me an "Invalid ID" message. I tryied also with ARN and it did not work.

Comment: In spite of the name, Canonical User ID does not, in fact, identify a user.  [Canonical User ID is an identifier for the entire AWS account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html).  You can't use this to give a single IAM user permissions on a bucket.

Comment: So what do we type in the "Enter an ID" field to give a user access to a bucket?

Comment: @JosephK the field you are referring to is to add another AWS _account_, not an IAM _user_. It is verified by making an HTTP call to the [GET service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTServiceGET.html): no matter the IAM user you use, the Owner.Id will always be the same. It also confused me until I bumped into this thread.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To grant permissions to an IAM user on a bucket, you'll need to create a Bucket Policy - which is an JSON document. The "Access for other AWS accounts" option in the ACL is for granting access to other (wholly separate) root AWS accounts, not for granting access to IAM users within your own root account.

### Creating/Editing a Policy

To access the bucket policy, browse to a bucket in the S3 web console. There you'll see the Overview/Properties/Permissions/Management tabs. Under Permissions there is a sub-tab called "Bucket Policy". At the bottom of the Bucket Policy page there is a link to a "Policy Generator", which will generate the JSON for you. (or the direct link is http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

### Identifying an IAM User to Assign Rights To

To identify the IAM user you want to grant permissions to, you'll use an ARN (Amazon Resource Name). The ARN format for IAM users is as follows: "arn:aws:iam::{Account-ID}:user/{Username}" (note the curly braces aren't part of the format). An example IAM ARN looks like this: **arn:aws:iam::100123456789:user/Daniel**

To get your numeric account ID, sign in as the root user and click your user name in the upper right corner of the page and choose "My Account" (which takes you to https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/account ). The account ID is listed under "Account Settings" at the top of the page.

Plug that user ARN into the "Principal" field of the policy generator, and choose which action(s) to grant to the user from the dropdown list.

### Specifying what to grant permissions on

To grant permissions to a bucket, or a set of files (objects) within a bucket you need to enter an ARN that identifies the bucket, or some subset of objects within the bucket into the "Amazon Resource Name" field (e.g. if I had a bucket called **daniels-stuff** and a folder in that bucket called **images** that I wanted to grant access to then I could provide an ARN such as **arn:aws:s3:::daniels-stuff/images/***

Hit "Add Statement" when you've put in the necessary information and then hit "Generate Policy". Note you can put multiple statements (access right assignments) into the one policy.

### More Info

Finally, there is a good primer to s3 bucket policies at https://brandonwamboldt.ca/understanding-s3-permissions-1662/ which includes some example policies.

Good luck (although I assume you've probably solved your issue now, others may find this helpful).

Comment: I faced this error when I am attempting to copy the Redis Elasticache backup to an s3 bucket. It is fixed after copy-pasting the canonical id given in the AWS document on the ACL of the S3 bucket.

Comment: very useful.  still, a bit incomprehensible that aws would make something so basic, well, not.

Answer (score 12):

The user's canonical ID is easiest to find by calling, as the user whose ID you want to find, aws s3api list-buckets:

```
aws --profile PROD s3api list-buckets
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "a-display-name",
        "ID": "a-64?-char-hex-string"  <<-- this HERE is the canonical user ID
    },
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "CreationDate": "2018-03-28T21:50:56.000Z",
            "Name": "bucket-1"
        },
        {
            "CreationDate": "2018-03-22T14:08:48.000Z",
            "Name": "bucket-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this ID, you can then call the s3api to grant access - eg to give read-access - like this:

```
aws --profile OTHER s3api put-object-acl \
    --bucket bucket-3 \
    --key path/to/file \
    --grant-read id="the-64-char-hex"
```

Answer (score 5):

To find Canonical ID of account follow the below steps:

1. Click on your username which is located in the top menu bar.
2. A drop down will appear. Select **My Security Credentials**.
3. Canonical user ID is there

Answer (score 4):

For getting the canonical ID, one of the simplest ways is to use CLI and run  `aws s3api list-buckets` command. You will get the ID in the output.

There are other ways also for getting the canonical ID and are clearly described in the aws docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html

list-buckets aws docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-buckets.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also get your Canonical ID for your IAM user from the CLI command:

List all the buckets and your iam Canonical ID:

```
aws s3api list-buckets
```

And if you just want to get your Canonical ID:

```
aws s3api list-buckets | grep ID
```

Keep in mind, the above commands are done via CLI where you would have set up your profile already.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Create a new policy using the following JSON**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:ListBucket",
              "s3:GetBucketLocation"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name_here>"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:ListBucket",
              "s3:DeleteObject",
              "s3:GetObjectVersion"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name_here>/*"
      }
  ]
}
```

**2. Assign the policy to the user or a user group

**Note:**

I kept on getting `Access Denied (Status code: 403)` errors because I was missing the first 2 objects in the JSON array above. You have to give your user permission to:

- See all your buckets
- List the specific bucket and get its location

before it even gets a chance to perform any actions on the bucket contents at all.

Comment: I get "Policy has invalid action" as response

Answer (score 2):

How to view the Canonical ID in AWS.

In the top Click your user Account drop down box .
Click My Security Credential.
In the console  Click the Account Identifiers
Pls don’s share your credential info.
[To view the Canonical ID in AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBwv2.png)

Pala ( VR.PL)

Answer (score 2):

paste this in the terminal

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query "Owner.ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have `*` at the end of the line to grant permissions to everything!

```
arn:aws:s3:::daniels-stuff/images/*
```

Answer (score -4):

There is another way to find your canonical name **in case you are not the ROOT user,**

You will need to log using CLI (using your access key and secret key) afterwards just type

**aws iam list-users**

and it will show the following information

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "UserName": "yoda",
            "PasswordLastUsed": "2018-02-24T17:47:15Z",
            "CreateDate": "2018-02-11T02:23:11Z",
            "UserId": "AIDASDY9WSX6QD",    <== Canonical Name
            "Path": "/",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::7783412456453:user/yoda"
        }
    ]
```

Note: The User ID and ARN  originals were edited :-)

I hope this will help

Neo

Comment: This is NOT the canonical UserID. The canonical User ID is a long alpha numeric string. It can usually be found by logging in to the AWS console, then from the top right click your username and from the drop down select 'Security Credentials'. You then need to expand the section for 'Account Identifiers'. NOTE: The IAM user obviously needs rights to access the console and view credentials.

Comment: From the CLI you can find it using: `aws s3api list-buckets | grep ID`